# Process code exited tith 1 while uploading project on AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I got the Error 'Same instance is running' and procedd code exited with 1 while uploading project through appengine . It was for rollback . So I run

```
pythonw.exe, '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=emailidhere', '--passin', 'rollback', 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\WORKING\\dimensions\\DimensionEndpoint'
```

But nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

1) Place your project app.yaml in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine".

2) Open cmd and change the directory to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine" using "cd" command

3) Run the command

```
python appcfg.py rollback app.yaml
```

4) Remove the app.yaml file from that folder after rollback as

The AppCfg command uses app.yaml information when you upload the app.